# Copiar (clone) um elemento SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

Quero "clonar" um rect SVG em JavaScript quando clico num botão. Tentei este código, mas não funcionou.

```
<svg id="svg">  
    <rect id="rect" x="5" y="25" width="50" height="50" stroke="#0E0E0E" style="fill:red; stroke-width:1" />
    <text id =txtrect x="5" y="35" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11" fill="white" >
        Rect1
    </text>
</svg>

function clone(){
    var newrect = document.getElementById('rect').cloneNode(true);
    newrect.setAttribute("x", 300);
    newrect.setAttribute("y", 300);
    newrect.style.position = 'absolute';
    document.getElementById("svg").appendChild(newrect);
}
```

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o "não funcionou"? O seu código funciona para mim. Eventualmente deve mudar o `x` e `y` para valores menores (para não sair fora da tela) e mudar a ID do elemento clonado. Pode mostrar como o seu código chama essa função?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, insira o clone no DOM, depois modifique os atributos (e certifique se de estar chamando a função `clone()` corretamente no seu código):

```
function clone(){
  var newrect = document.getElementById('rect').cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById('svg').appendChild(newrect);
  newrect.setAttribute("x", 100);
  newrect.setAttribute("y", 100);
}
```

### Demonstração:

```js
function clone(){
  var newrect = document.getElementById('rect').cloneNode(true);
  document.getElementById('svg').appendChild(newrect);
  newrect.setAttribute("x", 100);
  newrect.setAttribute("y", 100);
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg">  
  <rect id="rect" x="5" y="25" width="50" height="50" stroke="#0E0E0E" style="fill:red; stroke-width:1" />
  <text id="txtrect" x="5" y="35" font-family="Verdana" font-size="11" fill="white" >
    Rect1
  </text>
</svg>
<button onClick="clone();this.disabled=true">Clonar</button>
```

Comment: Obrigado, funciona. E agora quero mudar o id do objeto. Tento isso newrect.id = "rect2"; mas nao muda.

Comment: Tente `newrect.setAttribute( 'id', 'rect2' );` após por no DOM. De browser pra browser acho que as implementações variam um pouco.