# Adicionar objeto SVG dentro de um div dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, svg

Tenho um elemento SVG criado a partir de um clone. O que queria era inserir esse clone dentro de uma nova div. Usei este codigo.

```
function clone(){
        var newrect = document.getElementById('rect').cloneNode(true);
        document.getElementById("svg").appendChild(newrect);

        newrect.setAttribute("x", 100);
        newrect.setAttribute("y", 100);
        newrect.style.position = 'absolute';    


        var div = document.createElement('div');
        document.body.appendChild(div);
        div.id = 'div1';


        var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");
        div1.insertBefore(newrect, div1.firstChild);
}
```

Comment: Tem algum problema com o código? qual é o problema que tem? é a [continuação da outra pergunta?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37414/copiar-clone-um-elemento-svg)

Comment: Eu penso que cria a div, mas o meu objeto clone desaparece.

Comment: quer criar uma nova div com um `svg` dentro? se não pode explicar melhor pf...

Comment: Sim é mesmo isso. Quero que o objeto que foi copiado, esteja numa nova div, criada ('div1').

Comment: É isto que procura? http://jsfiddle.net/dgkcaf9q/

Comment: Sim é isso, mas tenho um problema com a posiçao. Porque tenho uma div antes do objecto svg. E funciona se tirar a position da div. como neste caso: http://jsfiddle.net/dgkcaf9q/4/

Comment: O problema é que elas estão em cima uma da outra. Se fizer float já funciona: http://jsfiddle.net/dgkcaf9q/5/ Se explicar em detalhe o que quer fazer vai ter mais ajuda do que se perguntar em exemplos demasiado espåecíficos...

Comment: Sim, o que quero fazer é mover um objeto svg com o mousse, e quando largar criar o clone na posicao onde o primeiro começou. O problema é que o objeto nao vai na posicao certa.

Comment: Dá para colocar um jsFiddle com o código completo que já tem? Quer mesmo fazer com um svg ou pode ser outro elemento?

Comment: sim, tem de ser num svg  http://jsfiddle.net/uLgkb8nr/

Comment: Seria algo como isto então? http://jsfiddle.net/uLgkb8nr/1/

Comment: é isso mesmo, obrigado. mas agora a mousse nao fica no meio do objeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sugiro então mudar o seu código da função clone para:

```
function clone() {
    var newrect = document.getElementById('svg').cloneNode(true);
    newrect.setAttribute("x", 100);
    newrect.setAttribute("y", 100);
    newrect.style.position = 'absolute';
    newrect.id = 'novoSVG';

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.height = '100px';
    div.style.width = '50px';
    addEvent(div, 'mousedown', function(e){ start_drag(div, e)});
    div.appendChild(newrect);
    document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/m5d52oah/

No fundo, e visto a div anterior ser retirada da posição inicial via drag e uma vez que dá position: absolute; à nova div, não precisa de se preocupar com a posição no DOM. Juntei também uma chamada à `start_drag()` para juntar um event handler à nova div.